# lldb "unable to resolve breakpoints" in private Objective-C classes?

Tags: objective-c, macos, reverse-engineering, lldb

As a lldb exercise, I am attempting to attach **lldb** to and set symbolic breakpoints in Apple's macOS TextEdit.app.  I am able to set breakpoints in Foundation classes.  But in private classes, it seems I always get *Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.*  Why?

I understand that shipped executables are stripped, but I also understand that Objective-C symbol names cannot be stripped, and have read several old articles explaining how to "crack" apps, and it looks like it worked for them, albeit with gdb.  And when I run `otool -ov` on the TextEdit executable, all of the private symbols and their addresses are shown.

**Example**

See how it works nicely for Foundation classes:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -F "-[NSString initWithFormat:]"
Breakpoint 1: where = Foundation`-[NSString initWithFormat:], address = 0x00007fff2c0c29d0
(lldb) breakpoint set -r '\[NSString .*\]$'
Breakpoint 2: 139 locations.
```

But it fails when I try the same in the private `Document` class, or in one of its methods which I found by using Steve Nygard's [class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/):

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -F "-[Document validateMenuItem:]"
Breakpoint 3: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
(lldb) breakpoint set -r '\[Document .*\]$'
Breakpoint 4: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, lldb only uses the ObjC runtime data to provide type information for methods when they get called in the expression parser.  It doesn't fold the methods found therein into the symbol table for breakpoint lookup.

Comment: Thank you, @Jim Ingham.  Are you saying that this is a feature which is not (yet) implemented in lldb?  Was it implemented in gdb?

Comment: Could one theoretically work around this getting the address for the method of interest in the otool report, and setting a breakpoint at that address?

Comment: First question, we never taught Apple's gdb to read the ObjC runtime data for any purpose.  I don't think the FSF gdb does this either.  We certainly could add this to lldb though I have no plans to at present.  File a radar with Apple's bug reporter if you want to vote for us adding this feature.

Comment: I think you can use the address you get from otool, but remember that libraries don't generally load at their static base address, so any address you get from grubbing in a binary will have to be slid to the actual load location of the library.  lldb's "image list" will show you the library's slide once you've run the program to the point where the relevant library got loaded.

Comment: Thanks again to @Jim Ingham.  So I'm reading up on Mach-O binary offsets and slides.

Comment: But what about, for example, this tutorial: https://www.mrspeaker.net/2011/01/06/mac-hacking/.  In there, one can search for and find this text: (gdb) break [XMLicensingWindowController isLicensed].  You see, that sets a symbolic breakpoint in a private class, and, reportedly, it worked!  How was it so easy back in 2011?

Comment: It used to be that folks would tend not to strip private ObjC symbols because they made crash traces easier to read.   But for various reasons (e.g. more focus on binary sizes) people seem to have gotten more aggressive about stripping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155971/discussion-between-jerry-krinock-and-jim-ingham).